# Cropping a PDF using Ghostscript 9.01

Tags: pdf, crop, ghostscript

I am not a programmer, but would like to learn how to crop a PDF using Ghostscript.

I have installed Ghostscript 9.01 in my machine.

Please guide me step by step process (starting from invoking Ghostscript) to crop a PDF with the specific coordinates.

I am even new to Ghostscript.

Answer (score 81):

First, take note that the measurement unit for PDF is the same as for PostScript: it's called a *point* [pt].

```
72 points == 1 inch == 25.4 millimeters
```

Assuming you have a page size of A4. Then the media dimensions are:

```
595 points width  == 210 millimeters
842 points height == 297 millimeters
```

Assuming you want to crop off:

```
   left edge: 24 points == 1/3 inch ~=  8.5 millimeters
  right edge: 36 points == 1/2 inch ~= 12.7 millimeters
    top edge: 48 points == 2/3 inch ~= 17.0 millimeters
 bottom edge: 72 points ==   1 inch ~= 25.4 millimeters
```

Then your Ghostscript commandline is this (on Windows):

```
gswin32c.exe                     ^
  -o cropped.pdf                 ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite              ^
  -c "[/CropBox [24 72 559 794]" ^
  -c " /PAGES pdfmark"           ^
  -f uncropped-input.pdf
```

Or on Linux:

```
gs                               \
  -o cropped.pdf                 \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite              \
  -c "[/CropBox [24 72 559 794]" \
  -c " /PAGES pdfmark"           \
  -f uncropped-input.pdf
```

However, this may not work reliably for all types of PDFs <sup>***[1]***</sup>. In those cases you should alternatively try these commands:

```
gswin32c.exe                 ^
  -o cropped.pdf             ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite          ^
  -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595    ^
  -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842   ^
  -dFIXEDMEDIA               ^
  -c "24 72 translate"       ^
  -c " 0 0 535 722 rectclip" ^
  -f uncropped-input.pdf
```

or

```
gs                           \
  -o cropped.pdf             \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite          \
  -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595    \
  -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842   \
  -dFIXEDMEDIA               \
  -c "24 72 translate"       \
  -c " 0 0 535 722 rectclip" \
  -f uncropped-input.pdf
```

---

***[^]*** : <sub>To be more specific: it will not work for PDFs which come along with their own `/CropBox` already defined to specific values. A dirty hack around that is to change the string `/CropBox` for all pages where it is desired to `/cROPBoX` (or similar case-changing) with a text editor prior to running the above GS command. The case-change effectively "disarms" the cropbox setting (without changing any PDF object offsets invalidating the existing `xref` table) so it is no longer considered by PDF renderers.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift response. This satisfy my requirements.

Comment: If you have no idea what the dimensions of the original pdf are you can try `gs -sDEVICE=bbox -f uncropped-input.pdf`

Comment: @jolly swagman: No, sorry, no-no-no! The `bbox` device does **NOT** indicate the 'dimensions' of the original PDF. It does indicate that (virtual) box on each page which would contain all marks on the printed or viewed page. One command that will work to get the dimensions ('MediaBox') for each page is: `pdfinfo -box some.pdf`.

Comment: @pipitas right, it only gives you a feel for the size of the page, but in future I will use `pdfinfo` as that seems much more useful.

Comment: Also, Google can help you with the conversion https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=10cm+in+points

Comment: *"However, this may not work reliably for all types of PDFs. In those cases you should alternatively try [...]"* Well, I have tried both with Ghostscript 9.10 and neither of them worked for me. On the other hand, [podofobox](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/tools.html) works and it is also much faster. See also [How to crop PDF margins using pdftk and /MediaBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5307825/341970)

Comment: @Ali: I also know `podofobox`, and know that it works. Also I'm familiar with some other commandline tools. But the OP explicitly asked about *Ghostscript*, and and stated that he liked to learn using Ghostscript. And that's what the answer dealt with... ;-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle My previous comment is for those future visitors who try the things in your answer and fail. Sorry, I probably should have stated that in my comment. I did not downvote your answer, it is most likely *the* answer to the question. However, my goal was to crop the damn PDF at hand no matter how. :)

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I have [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/592206/161463) a related question over at askubuntu. My answer provides a small bash script to simplify the process and I explain a method to determine the coordinates. Maybe you want to add the link in your answer?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle The line   `-c "24 72 translate        \ ` lack a closing `"` as well as the Windows version. I cannot edit the post as diff is less than 6 characters x)

Comment: @hdl: I think you *still* could have edited the post (even without the trick of adding more blanks): if you write a longer comment, why+what you edited, it should work.

Comment: Are left/right/top/bottom the same when PDF orientation is landscape? I cannot manage to make either of your commands work for an a3/landscape PDF that I'd like to crop to a4/portrait (removing 595pt from the left)

Comment: @hdl: Yes they are the same. Be careful however if a `90 rotate` command is involved somewhere.... Check with `pdfinfo -box -l 100 the.pdf` what the `/Media/Crop/Art/Trim&/BleedBox` settings are for the first 100 pages, as well as their rotational status (indicated by `rot: ...`.

Comment: Well I must have mistyped something in the first place for your first command worked the 2nd time, thanks! FWIW, rot value was 0.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for a script to do it, I created a bash function for this:

```
function crop_pdf() {
    input=$1
    output=$6

    pdf_info=$(pdfinfo -box $input)
    currentWidth=$(echo "$pdf_info" | grep "Page size:" | awk '{print $3}')
    currentHeight=$(echo "$pdf_info" | grep "Page size:" | awk '{print $5}')

    left=$2
    bottom=$3
    right=$(echo "$currentWidth - $4" | bc)
    top=$(echo "$currentHeight - $5" | bc)

    gs -o $output -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/CropBox [$left $bottom $right $top] /PAGES pdfmark" -f $input
}
```

The usage is simple:

```
crop_pdf input.pdf left bottom right top output.pdf
```

For example:

```
crop_pdf mypdf.pdf 20 30 10 33 mypdf-cropped.pdf
```

In this example the command will remove 20 points from the left, 30 from the bottom, 10 from the right and 33 from the top.

"Points" is the measure explained above in the Kurt Pfeifle's answer.

I'm not 100% sure if it works with all the pdfs, but I think it could work.

This script needs the following:

- [Ghostscript](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ghostscript)
- [bc](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bc)
- [pdfinfo](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xpdf) (xpdf contains the pdfinfo command)

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers just change the /CropBox view port of a file not actually crop a PDF content let me explain pictorially. Using one of the commands from previous answer to "Crop" the GhostScript supplied "Escher" Sample. We might note that the amount of "crop" in the result here on the left is aggressive and "cuts" the contents.

[image]

That is not so, the content is still there and we can use autocrop to restore the source image. so "crop" box is a re-movable viewport into the MediaBox.

To physically "Trim" a PDF (similar to redact all 4 sides) we need to use a function such as MuPDF mutool "trim" command.

Answer (score 0):

I started by getting the dimensions of my file with

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bbox myFile.pdf
```

Which outputs something like this for every page in the PDF

```
%%BoundingBox: 16 14 585 781
%%HiResBoundingBox: 16.991999 14.904000 584.207068 780.500015
```

Then, based on those values, I ran this second command to crop all pages

```
gs -o cropped.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=430 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=781 -dFIXEDMEDIA -f myFile.pdf
```

---

Using GhostScript 10.02.1

```
gs --version
10.02.1
```

Comment: It cuts starting from left bottom corner. How to set other starting point?