# Undo Pdfnup Operation

Tags: pdf, undo

I have a Pdf file which contains several slides per page, including text (not only images).
This pdf was probably created using pdfnup.
Can I revert the pdfnup operation so that each slide is shown on one page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no simple to be used *'undo'* operation.

However, the following answers show you the approach principle, how you can achieve the undo-equivalent operation using Ghostscript:

- [**Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page**](https://superuser.com/a/189109/40894) (Superuser)
- [**How can I split a PDF's pages down the middle?**](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894) (Superuser)
- [**Cropping a PDF using Ghostscript 9.01**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184547/359307) (Stackoverflow)
- [**PDF - Remove White Margins**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418720/359307) (Stackoverflow)

<sub>*(Should these not help you to find the final solution, ask again. But then to come up with a fully working commandline, I'd need the complete output of the following command first: `pdfinfo -f 1 -l 100 -box your.pdf`.)*</sub>

Comment: The descriptions worked well, I used `pdfjam` for trimming though.