# Extract images from PDF page section

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I need extract images from a PDF page section.

For example consider there is a PDF page which has couple of images on top of the page & couple of images on bottom of the page. I want to extract the images on top of the page.

So far what I tried is :

- Using ghostscript cropped the pdf - `gs -o$croppedPdfFilepath -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/CropBox [31.46 690.22 560.54 839]" -c "/PAGES pdfmark" -sPageList=12 -f $originalPdfFilepath`
- Then pass the cropped image to pdfimages to extract the images - `pdfimages -j "$croppedPdfFilepath" $outputDirectory/image`

But the problem is `pdfimages` is extracting all the images on that page (From the top & the bottom), even though when I view the cropped PDF it has only the images on top of the page.

After some research it looks like the `CropBox` only hides the cropped content from view but the PDF source still has the content.

Any guidance to remove the content from the PDF page or any other approach will be helpful. I'm using `php` to do it programatically.

References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184547/4273867

Comment: If you're only interested in getting the top and bottom images, would it be viable to just get the first and last result returned by pdfimages?

Comment: @Moudi Hey, I'm interested on getting only the images from top of the page

Comment: In that case, is the first image in ```pdfimages``` the image on the top of the page? If that's correct, then you would be able to achieve this by just getting the very first element in ```pdfimages```

Comment: @Moudi So the number of images is dynamic. It can be one or five or N. I won't know how many there before hand. I can calculate where the photos section starts & ends. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Permanent removal of content from a PDF or PDF page is termed "redaction". So there's a search term to get you started...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract images based on their page position, you can do it pretty easily with `pdftohtml` by parsing the output and then checking for the position of elements using their xml attributes. Here's a very basic example that puts the full path of images in an array if they are positioned less than `200` from the top:

```php
$pdf   = '/path/to/test.pdf';
$files = [];
$xml   = shell_exec('pdftohtml -stdout -xml ' . $pdf);
$dom   = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('image');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $top = $image->getAttribute('top');
    if ($top < 200) {
        $files[] = dirname($pdf) . '/' . $image->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
print_r($files);
```

Note, contrary to the man page for `pdftohtml`, which indicates that it *"generates its output in the current working directory"*, my experience is that it will always generate output in the same directory as the pdf being read.

Comment: This solution looks promising. I'll give a try and let you know. Thanks